# SqlAlchemy - How update a reference to a foreign table via associationproxy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, many-to-one

I have an [association_proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) set up on a `Fruit` class that references a `FruitStatus` class: `Fruit.status = association_proxy('statusObject', 'name')`. I'd like to be able to change a Fruit's `status` field without there being an `UPDATE` on the `FruitStatuses` table.

Currently, if I instantiate a new Fruit with something like, then change the status, the row in FruitStatuses gets updated, instead of the foreign key in Fruit being updated:

```
# Create an apple that's 'good'
apple = Fruit(name='apple', status='good')
session.merge(apple)
session.commit()

# Shows: (1, good), (2, rotten)
print(session.query(FruitStatus).all())

# Update the status to 'rotten'
apple.status = 'rotten'
session.merge(apple)
session.commit()
print(session.query(FruitStatus).all())

# Shows: (1, rotten), (2, rotten)
```

I'd like for the reference to change to the row whose foreign key is 2, rather than update the original row.

Below is a full working example.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

metadata = MetaData()

fruitStatusTable = Table(
    'FruitStatuses', metadata,
    Column('status_id', Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True),
    Column('name', String(256))
)

fruitsTable = Table(
    'Fruits', metadata,
    Column('fruit_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('status_id', Integer, ForeignKey('FruitStatuses.status_id')),
    Column('name', String(256)),
    Column('revision', Integer, nullable=False)
)

class FruitStatus(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        for key in kwds:
            setattr(self, key, kwds[key])
            pass
        return
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}<status_id={}, name={}>".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.status_id, self.name)

class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        for key in kwds:
            setattr(self, key, kwds[key])
            pass
        return
    def __repr__(self):
        ret = []
        for key in sorted(self.__dict__):
            if key == '_sa_instance_state':
                continue
            ret.append("{}: {}".format(key, self.__dict__[key]))
            pass
        return "{}<{}>".format(self.__class__.__name__, ret)


engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

mapper(FruitStatus, fruitStatusTable)

goodStatus = FruitStatus(status_id=1, name='good')
rottenStatus = FruitStatus(status_id=2, name='rotten')
session.add(goodStatus)
session.add(rottenStatus)
session.commit()

#mapper(Resource, resourcesTable)
mapper(Fruit, fruitsTable,
    version_id_col=fruitsTable.c.revision,
    properties={
        "statusObject": relationship(FruitStatus)
    })
Fruit.status = association_proxy("statusObject", 'name', creator=lambda status: goodStatus if status=='good' else rottenStatus)

apple = Fruit(name='apple', status='good')
apple = session.merge(apple)
session.commit()

print("Getting statuses before change")
print(session.query(FruitStatus).all())

apple.status = 'rotten'
session.add(apple)
session.commit()

print("Getting statuses after change")
print(session.query(FruitStatus).all())
```

Comment: Change the `statusObject` instead?

Comment: @IljaEverilä yep, that's definitely an option. Doing so would introduce some complexity to the Fruit, though, since it would need to do a lookup to figure out which status name is associated with what FruitStatus. It's not difficult, but it's a little weird if I wanted to keep Fruit from knowing about the statusObject (and defeats the reason I'm using the association proxy in the first place). I'll definitely do this and just remove the association proxy altogether if nothing else comes up.